# Как получить значение виджета Tk.Entry находящемся в списке?

Tags: python, массивы, ооп, list, tkinter

Есть список *entries = []*, в котором находятся создаваемые с помощью *tk.Spinbox* виджеты *tk.Entry*

```
def update_entries():
    name_to = int(spinbox.get())
    tvip = int(spinbox.get())
    qotk = int(spinbox.get())
    number_group = int(spinbox.get())


    label_name = ttk.Label(root, text = "Наименование")
    label_name.grid(column = 1, row = 7)
    label_time = ttk.Label(root, text = "tвып")
    label_time.grid(column = 2, row = 7)
    label_q = ttk.Label(root, text = "q")
    label_q.grid(column = 3, row = 7)
    label_group = ttk.Label(root, text = "группа")
    label_group.grid(column = 4, row = 7)
    
    for entry in entries:
        entry.destroy()

    for label_number in labels:
        label_number.destroy()


    for i in range(name_to):
        # label_name = ttk.Label(root, text = "Наименование")
        # label_name.grid(column = 1, row = 7)
        label_number = ttk.Label(root, text=i+1)
        label_number.grid(column=0, row=8*(i+1))
        entry_name_i = tk.Entry(root)
        entry_name_i.grid(row=8*(i+1), column=1, padx = (0,50))
        entries.append(entry_name_i)
        labels.append(label_number)

    for i in range(tvip):
        # label_time = ttk.Label(root, text = "tвып")
        # label_time.grid(column = 2, row = 7)
        entry_time_i = tk.Entry(root)
        entry_time_i.grid(row=8*(i+1), column=2)
        entries.append(entry_time_i)

    for i in range(qotk):
        # label_q = ttk.Label(root, text = "q")
        # label_q.grid(column = 3, row = 7)
        entry_q_i = tk.Entry(root)
        entry_q_i.grid(row=8*(i+1), column=3)
        entries.append(entry_q_i)

    for i in range(number_group):
        # label_group = ttk.Label(root, text = "группа")
        # label_group.grid(column = 4, row = 7)
        entry_group_i = tk.Entry(root)
        entry_group_i.grid(row=8*(i+1), column=4)
        entries.append(entry_group_i)

spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=20, command=update_entries, width = 5)
spinbox.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
```

Из создаваемых *Entry* нужно получить вводимые пользователем значения, для дальнейшего построения графика. Как это можно было бы сделать, если мне инетрпритатор выдает ошибку, что таких *entry* нет, так как названия их *!entry5, !entry6* и т.д.
Я пробовал достать из списка *entries = []* с помощью **get()**, но ошибка все та же. Как можно получить значения?

Comment: entry.destroy() не удаляет объекты из списка, а только уничтожает их. У вас уничтоженные объекты в списке остаются, вы видимо из них текст пытаетесь получить. А так код типа `entries[0].get()` вполне должен работать.